# Problem analyzing Dirac equation in an arbitrary coordinate system using geometric calculus

Tags: dirac-equation, differential-equations, clifford-algebra

> This question was partially inspired from [the Dirac equation in spherical coordinates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/611503/derivation-of-dirac-matrices-in-spherical-polar-coordinates).

For simplicity, let’s suppose I have a two variable partial differential equation initially written in a Cartesian basis $\mathbf{\{e_x, e_y\}}$, obeying the usual commutation relations of a Clifford algebra $Cl(\Bbb{R})_{1,0}$ as shown below

$$\mathbf{e_x}P(x,y) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+ \mathbf{e_y}Q(x,y) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0 \tag{1}$$

With $P$ and $Q$ some scalar functions.

Now, I change my variables into $x,y \rightarrow x’,y’$ and get the new equation

$$\mathbf{e_x’}P’(x’,y’) \frac{\partial u’}{\partial x’}+ \mathbf{e_y}’Q’(x’,y’) \frac{\partial u’}{\partial y’}=0 \tag{2}$$

Plus the explicit coordinate change equations

$$\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{e_x’}=a(x’,y’)\mathbf{e_x}+b(x’,y’)\mathbf{e_y}\\
\mathbf{e_y’}=c(x’,y’)\mathbf{e_x}+d(x’,y’)\mathbf{e_y}
\end{equation*} \tag{3}$$

$a,b,c,d$ scalar functions.

My question is: If I try to integrate equation $(2)$ do I have to use the explicit transformation equations $(3)$? or should I keep $\mathbf{\{e_x’, e_y’\}}$ as some abstract basis vectors and integrate the equation purely in terms of the new coordinates?

My paradox here is the fact that, on one hand, when solving equation $(2)$ some derivatives of $\mathbf{e_x}’$ and $\mathbf{e_y}’$ in terms of the new variables ($x’,y’$) may arise, and by looking into $(3)$ I definitely can see that there are dependence on them. Again, a cool aspect of Cartesian basis vectors is that they are the same everywhere, therefore can be consider constant. On the other hand, why should I bother to write my new equation in terms of the old basis vectors? However, if I insist on this I would have to consider this new basis vectors as constant and their derivatives would vanish, right?

---

PS: This question is all about geometric calculus or math in our universe, so please, consider only that when answering. Still, I couldn’t resist imagining a physical situation that deepens my paradox. In a universe where the new basis vectors $\mathbf{\{e_x’,e_y’\}}$ where their “natural” one. In this case, it would look weird to go to a Cartesian basis, or totally impossible as they may not even be aware of that.